# How can I rebind command and control in the context of terminal applications?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, keybindings

I'm on macOS Ventura 13.1. I have the command and control modifier keys swapped in the macOS keyboard settings, and it works in most places, but terminal programs still expect command+X to close nano, or command+C to kill a process, etc., but I'd prefer they use control+X or control+C to be consistent with the rest of the system.

Is there a way to *fully* rebind these modifier keys so that they work globally in all programs, including terminals like iTerm2 and VS Code's integrated terminal? I tried using Karabiner Elements, but that didn't work inside terminals either.

Comment: Terminals expect Ctrl/key. People mainly just get used to that fact that they want 'the other one' compared to the rest of the system.

Comment: Use `hidutil` to remap keys systemwide.  Similar question:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/434991/119271

Comment: @Allan Thanks for the tip! I just tried that, and it looks like it doesn't fix the problem inside terminals. That change makes it function the same way as rebinding through System Settings does--the binding works in most places, but terminals still require command.

Comment: It should work everywhere. Did you close and restart Terminal?

Comment: @Allan Yes, I restarted the terminal. Pressing ctrl+V does paste into the terminal, so iTerm2 in this case is recognizing the command, but if I go into nano within the terminal, I have to hit command+X to close it. I think I understand now what Tetsujin is saying, that this is just the nature of how keybinds work on macOS and there's probably no solution to this.

Comment: I'll I have to research some more because it should be changed systemwide